# Prove that set of all lines in the plane is uncountable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

> Let $L$ be the set of all lines in the plane. Prove that $L$ is uncountable, but only countably many of the lines in $L$ contain more than one rational point.

**Attempt**: Well, I was trying to define $L$ using linear combinations of points since a line is a linear combo of two points. So, I wanted to define $L=\{ax+yb:x+y+z=k,k∈Z_+\}$. But, this does not seem right. Anyway, once I define $L$ I would try to find a function from $L$ to some **uncountable** set D that is onto or a function from D to L that is 1-1. Help appreciated thank you.

Comment: There are at least as many distinct lines as there are real numbers. Now if a line contains two rational points then every point on the line is also rational.

Comment: @Chiruno "if a line contains two rational points then every point on the line is also rational" obviously not.

Comment: Ah crap, forget that. I was mixing myself up with linear combinations. To redeem my previous blunder, a line with two rational points will intersect the x-y axis at a rational point.

Comment: @Koba Actually say something about what you have tried. Saying "I have little idea where to start" is useless.

Comment: For the second part, You could use a combination of the theorem that the rationals are countable and then use [Cantor's Pairing Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function) or a variant of it.

Comment: Think of how many points you need to uniquely define/specify a line in the plane.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Well, I was trying to define $L$ using linear combinations of points since a line is a linear combo of two points. So, I wanted to define $L=\{ax+yb: x+y+z=k, k \in Z_+\}$. But, this does not seem right. Anyway, once I define $L$ I would try to find a function from $L$ to some uncountable set $D$ that is onto or a function from $D$ to $L$ that is 1-1 .

Comment: You can find a function, e.g., using the coefficients $a,b$, since for every pair of coefficients, you get a line.

Comment: @user99680 good point, but I want to make sure I define $L$ properly which I have a hard time with.

Comment: For the second question: how many pairs of rational points are there?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott infinitely many I am guessing.

Comment: Certainly infinitely many, but what *kind* of infinite?

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: the "A lot"type of infinite? Just kidding, but there is the fact that the lines overlap.

Comment: @user99680: One of the two types named in the question.

Comment: @Brian M Scott: I was just kidding; please see my post above your previous.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott countably infinite, i.e. the set of all pairs of rational points is denumerable.

Comment: @Koba: Right, and each line containing two or more rational points is determined by two of those rational points, so there are only ...

Comment: @BrianM.Scott n pairs of rational points, $n\in N$? Sorry, for being too dense.

Comment: @Koba: There may be more than one pair of points per line, but that doesn’t hurt. Each pair of rational points determines exactly one of the lines that contain two or more rational points, and there are only countably many pairs of rational points, so ...

Comment: @BrianM.Scott there are countably many lines!!!

Comment: @Koba: That’s right: that argument shows that there are only countably many lines that contain more than one rational point.

Comment: @Koba : the question in your title is trivial.  For the benefit of future readers, could you please alter the title to match your actual question better?

Comment: @StefanSmith ok. I did not know it is trivial though.

Comment: @Koba : I'm sorry if my comment seemed condescending.  Maybe I should have written "obvious" rather than "trivial".  The set of all vertical lines has the same cardinality as the set of all real numbers, and you probably already know the real numbers are an uncountable set.  So the set of _all_ lines in the plane has to be uncountable.  The problem is not that the question in the title is "trivial", but that the title does not really match the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can List all lines in the plane this way:

Use the fact that a line is described uniquely once you know its slope, and one of its
intercepts with the axes. The slope is indexed by the Reals, and so is the intercept, say the x-intercept. So we count all the possible pairs ( slope, x-intercept), and show
it is equal to $|\mathbb R|$

1) Consider all lines thru the origin $(0,0)$.  These are described uniquely by their
slope, and there are $|\mathbb R|$ of them, since the slope is parametrized by the Reals.

2) From 1) , we can cover all other cases of lines not going thru $(0,0)$ , by considering all possible ( say x-) intercepts of a line thru any point, with fixed slope$m$. For every line
in 1), there are $\mathbb R$ lines not going thru the origin, but with the same slope.
This means there are $|\mathbb R|\times |\mathbb R|=|\mathbb R|$ total lines in the plane.

Comment: You forget all the lines with "infinite" slope; lines perpendicular to the x-axis.

Comment: That doesn't affect the cardinality in the end; you're just adding one line.

Comment: I am adding an uncountable infinity of lines, which you neglected. That is significantly more than "one line."

Comment: No, I meant one line at each interval. And I did include the horizontal line in the count. Still, even considering your description,if you have $|\mathbb R|$ lines at each point, throwing-in the horizontal line does not affect the cardinality of the collection; you still have $\mathbb R$ lines; just include that line, and the cardinality. The collection of all finite $m$ union an additional line And you're not including uncountably-many, there is just one for every interval $[n,n+1]$. So I do not see how my calculations are incorrect.

Comment: If you had just asked, I would have clarified the fact that I am including the horizontal line in my count. Basically, I am including the possibility of $m=\infty$ in my count. It is your unwarranted assumption that leads you to believe I am undercounting. And you may want to make your own argument more rigorous.

Comment: (Cont.) if you believe mine is not rigorous-enough. Besides, the question is about giving an accurate "count" (cardinality), not that of giving an accurate description of the set.

Comment: An accurate description of the set will allow an accurate proof of cardinality; and you are entering a pissing match over whose answer is better. Comments are for critiquing answers to a question.

Comment: What pissing match? you made unwarranted assumptions (which are false in this case) over my post, instead of asking. So I'm just replying in kind.

Comment: unwarranted assumptions in this case are probably me misunderstanding your answer and I concede your point, partially because I tire of this discourse. Good day.

Comment: Just a quick thing: if you could please address these issues shortly after the answer is posted; it is easier to address them under these conditions.Of course, if you believe there is something incorrect, no problem bringing things up at any point. Peace.

Answer (score 1):

All lines in the plane are a superset of all lines perpendicular to a given line.

How is it with perpendicular lines, points on their parent line and the number of points on a line?

Comment: What do you mean by " How is it with perpendicular lines, ...", that is too much hand-waving.

Comment: If you believe my argument lacks rigor, you may want to make your own argument more rigorous.

Comment: @user99680 This is obviously a homework question. I am not going to do this gentleperson's homework for them. Besides, my answer goes at presenting a partial answer from a strategy independent of the orientation of the plane, and indeed independent of linear equations in the plane. This is elementary set theory, not analysis.

Comment: The reason I brought it up is because you seemed to be saying my answer was not rigorous-enough.

Comment: @user99680 and that is for you to take to the comment thread of your own answer.

Comment: I did bring it up there.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Let L be a line in the plane and v some vector that does not generates that line. You can prove that for every pair of real numbers (a,b), L+bv and L+av have empty intersection. For the second part, try this idea:
Every line with a irrational slope contains only one rational point (prove it by contradiction).